# MongoDB delete session

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express-sessions

Есть проблема, нужно удалить сессию зная userLogin, никак не могу составить запрос.
I need to create a delete request of a session. The only one thing I know is a userLogin. Some tries below.
[image]

[image]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит никак не могу составить запрос? У вас запрос составлен. Может быть он составлен не правильно и что то не работает или работает не так как вы ожидали? Если так, то не соизволите ли вы рассказать нам об этом?

Comment: Мой косяк. Не упомянул, что все мои попытки удалить запись были неудачны. Запись остается в бд. Причем при явном копировании id из бд и запросе collection.deleteOne({_id: "скопированный id"}) все работает и запись удаляется. Проблема в составлении запроса так чтобы он находил запись по логину и удалял ее. В element храниться верный логин, спец проверял консолью

Comment: Выглядит так, как будь то у вас в поле `session` лежит JSON строка а не объект. Это возможно?